# Need help for increasing size of home directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, disk-space

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I am unable to find a solution for my problem.

So as the title implies, I have recently installed ubuntu 20.04, dual boot along with Windows 10. I was installing anaconda yesterday for python and after everything was done, I received the message that "FILEROOT has 600 MB memory left"(Sorry, but dont have the screenshot of it). On looking further, I found that the home directory indeed had less storage space. Here is attached the output of df -aTh on terminal:

```
Filesystem     Type             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
sysfs          sysfs               0     0     0    - /sys
proc           proc                0     0     0    - /proc
udev           devtmpfs         3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
devpts         devpts              0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs          tmpfs            769M  2.3M  767M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5 ext4              16G   14G  1.3G  92% /
securityfs     securityfs          0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs          tmpfs            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup2        cgroup2             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/unified
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore         pstore              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/pstore
efivarfs       efivarfs            0     0     0    - /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
none           bpf                 0     0     0    - /sys/fs/bpf
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup         cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
systemd-1      autofs              0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
hugetlbfs      hugetlbfs           0     0     0    - /dev/hugepages
mqueue         mqueue              0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
debugfs        debugfs             0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
tracefs        tracefs             0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/tracing
fusectl        fusectl             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
configfs       configfs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/config
/dev/loop0     squashfs          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop1     squashfs          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop2     squashfs         219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop3     squashfs          66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop4     squashfs          51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop6     squashfs          65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop5     squashfs         219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop7     squashfs          32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11036
/dev/loop8     squashfs          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12398
/dev/loop9     squashfs          52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat             246M   84M  163M  35% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs            769M   20K  769M   1% /run/user/125
gvfsd-fuse     -                   -     -     -    - /run/user/125/gvfs
tmpfs          tmpfs            769M   68K  769M   1% /run/user/1000
gvfsd-fuse     fuse.gvfsd-fuse     0     0     0    - /run/user/1000/gvfs
/dev/fuse      fuse                0     0     0    - /run/user/1000/doc
tmpfs          tmpfs            769M  2.3M  767M   1% /run/snapd/ns
nsfs           nsfs                0     0     0    - /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt
```

So is there a way by which I can increase storage space of my home directory? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 2 : Here is the output of sudo fdisk -l. I hope this works.

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 55.48 MiB, 58159104 bytes, 113592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.45 MiB, 58134528 bytes, 113544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 50.98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 218.102 MiB, 229629952 bytes, 448496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 64.79 MiB, 67915776 bytes, 132648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 31.9 MiB, 32595968 bytes, 63664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: KBG40ZNS256G NVMe KIOXIA 256GB          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8C2D4B07-EF83-462C-8910-D2DB2D83CD4C

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    514047    512000   250M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    514048    776191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    776192 462952447 462176256 220.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 462952448 464979967   2027520   990M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 464979968 497395711  32415744  15.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 497395712 500117503   2721792   1.3G Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3542D087-7CE6-4F88-90AE-5160120DF86A

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     264191     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2      264192 1030658047 1030393856 491.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  1030658048 1953521663  922863616 440.1G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/loop8: 32.29 MiB, 33853440 bytes, 66120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 51.4 MiB, 53522432 bytes, 104536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Add the output of `fdisk -l`.

Comment: @harrymc I edited the post, but dont know why I am unable to embed pictures. Its directly setting it as a link or something

Comment: Not very useful. Try `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: @harrymc I have edited the post.